# DartDoc: How do I display DartPad in the documentation for my Flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, dartdoc

I'm trying to create documentation using [DartDoc](https://pub.dev/packages/dartdoc) for my components in my Flutter app for my colleagues to use. So far I have managed to display the docs. But I need to provide a sample code in dartpad using [Snippets](https://pub.dev/packages/snippets).

This is the code:

````dart
/// A basic button, which consists of a content, typically a text, in a filled container.
///
/// {@tool snippet}
/// TEST: Create snippet...
///
/// ```dart
/// CircleAvatar(
///   backgroundImage: NetworkImage(userAvatarUrl),
/// )
/// ```
/// {@end-tool}
///
/// {@tool dartpad}
/// TEST: Create dartpad snippet...
///
/// ** See code in examples/api/lib/widgets/atoms/button/button.0.dart **
/// {@end-tool}
class NeuButton extends StatelessWidget {
````

However, the `@tool` tag doesn't render as it should. The result looked like this:

[image: @tool not rendering]

Tried setting up `dartdoc_options.yaml` like so:

```yaml
dartdoc:
  include: [Atoms, Components, Templates, Helpers]
  tools:
    snippet:
      command:
        [ 'bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart', 'pub', 'global', 'run', 'snippets', '--output-directory=doc/snippets', '--type=snippet' ]
      description: 'Creates sample code documentation output from embedded documentation samples.'
    sample:
      command:
        [ 'bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart', 'pub', 'global', 'run', 'snippets', '--output-directory=doc/snippets', '--type=sample' ]
      description: 'Creates full application sample code documentation output from embedded documentation samples.'
    dartpad:
      command:
        [ 'bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart', 'pub', 'global', 'run', 'snippets', '--output-directory=doc/snippets', '--type=dartpad' ]
      description: 'Creates full application sample code documentation output from embedded documentation samples and displays it in an embedded DartPad.'
```

I wasn't sure how to use the `bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart` part, so I just copied the  `bin` folder from the Flutter repo, but that still didn't work.

So the question is how do I make the **snippet** work, especially the `{@tool dartpad}`?

---

Just in case, this is the command process how I run the dartdoc:

1. `flutter pub global activate dartdoc`
2. `dart pub global activate snippets`
3. `flutter pub global run dartdoc .`
4. `flutter pub global activate dhttpd`
5. `dhttpd --path doc/api`

Versions:

- dartdoc 5.1.2
- snippets 0.2.5
- dhttpd 4.0.1

My `flutter doctor -v` result:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.4, on macOS 11.6.6 20G624 darwin-x64, locale en-ID)
    • Flutter version 2.10.4 at /Users/lpt530/Library/Flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision c860cba910 (2 months ago), 2022-03-25 00:23:12 -0500
    • Engine revision 57d3bac3dd
    • Dart version 2.16.2
    • DevTools version 2.9.2

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/lpt530/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 30.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Users/lpt530/Library/Android/sdk
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.5.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    ! Flutter recommends a minimum Xcode version of 13.
      Download the latest version or update via the Mac App Store.
    • CocoaPods version 1.10.1

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.67.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.42.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • macOS (desktop) • macos  • darwin-x64     • macOS 11.6.6 20G624 darwin-x64
    • Chrome (web)    • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 102.0.5005.61

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available
```